# Add a normal distribution line in histogram

Tags: r, lines

I've met a weird problem that I can't figure it out totally.
I'm supposed to add a normal distribution line upon a histogram.I input every step's code but after typing lines function there's no response. I don't know what's wrong.Hope anyone help me!
MY code are:

```
grades<-mydata$Exam1
hist(grades,breaks=20,freq=T) #A correct histogram comes out.
mean(grades,na.rm=T) #there is NA in the column so I remove it when calculating mean.
[1] 75.15278

sd(grades,na.rm=T)  
[1] 16.97443 

x<-seq(0,100,0.01) 
y<-dnorm(x,mean=mean(grades,na.rm=T),sd=sd(grades,na.rm=T))
lines(x,y)#and there's no response!no line showed up!
```

Is anything wrong with my code?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume it's R code - then try this:

```
grades <- mydata$Exam1
hist(grades, prob=TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(grades), sd=sd(grades)), add=TRUE)
```

Note that if you compare normal distribution to the histogram, you probably want histogram to display probabilities rather than frequencies.

Comment: Good point.  Or he could normalize the hist$counts values returned by the function.

Answer (score 4):

You want `hist(*, freq=FALSE)`, not `freq=TRUE`.

Comment: ?  what does that have to do with his calculation of `x` and `y` ?

Comment: @carlwitthoft Nothing. The calculation of x and y is fine, the histogram is plotted on the wrong scale for the density to appear.